# How to encrypt data with RSA x509 2048 public key in JS/Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography, rsa

Prompt the module to work with [This encryption](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/rsa-encryption-decryption)

Something goes wrong with crypto

```
const encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt( { key: `MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDAW3P7gObqvIjJA3L7ZMVDdJ5lLis4jpShq14xWtS3AvnStWV4xY2BQ74bE08PvomByQc585vM7/HQNj2JNwQXwbjhyL5noC5Da3YGt5RiPMARa61LVeBcN8pipJNZoaFSrpMeG1CE45NMNhAnphv0WXzdX+9sr2uateIOi3Ab5QIDAQAB`, padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING, }, Buffer.from(cardData), );
```

error

```
Error: error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported at Object.publicEncrypt (node:internal/crypto/cipher:79:12)
```

I also tried like this, but still the same error

```
const publicKey = Buffer.from(    'MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDAW3P7gObqvIjJA3L7ZMVDdJ5lLis4jpShq14xWtS3AvnStWV4xY2BQ74bE08PvomByQc585vM7/HQNj2JNwQXwbjhyL5noC5Da3YGt5RiPMARa61LVeBcN8pipJNZoaFSrpMeG1CE45NMNhAnphv0WXzdX+9sr2uateIOi3Ab5QIDAQAB',
      'base64',
    );
    const encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(
      {
        key: publicKey,
        padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING,
      },
      Buffer.from(cardData, 'base64'),
    );
```

Comment: The first approach requires a PEM encoded key (your code lacks header, footer and line breaks). The second approach uses a DER encoded key and therefore needs an additional `format` and `type` specification, see the docs for `publicEncrypt()`: *If key is not a KeyObject, this function behaves as if key had been passed to [crypto.createPublicKey()](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatepublickeykey)*.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, but it worked when I put the key in a file, but I can't understand why

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFdAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAv5yse9ka3ZQE0feuGtem
Yv3IqOlLck8zHUM7lTrdza6lXTszRSXfdO7jMb+L5C7e2QNFs+7sIX2OQJ6a+HG8
kr+jwJ4tS3c1sWtd9NXpsU40PE4MeNE5RqiNXjcDxA+L4OsEm/BlyFOEOh2epGyY
Ud5/iO3OiQFRNicomT2saQYAeqIwuELPs1XpLk9HLx5qPbm8fRrQhjeUD5TLO8b+
4yCnObe8vy/BMUwBfq+ieWADIjwWCMp2KTpMGLz48qnaD9kdrYJ0iyHqzb2mkDhd
Izkim24A3lWoYitJCBrrB2xM05sm9+OdCI1f7nPNJbl5URHobSwR94IRGT7CJcUj
vwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

and then read it

```
const publicKey = fs.readFileSync('./rsaprivkey_public.key');
    const encryptedData = crypto.publicEncrypt(
      {
        key: Buffer.from(publicKey),
        padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING,
      },
      Buffer.from(cardData),
    );
```

Comment: *...but I can't understand why...*: In your answer you use a PEM encoded key, in your question you do not.